# How do I use regex to insert srt files into mysql?

Tags: php, regex

I have a directory of SRT files, formated:

```
8
00:00:45,879 --> 00:00:50,680
- Oh! Just leave me in the car with the window open a crack.
- That's the plan.

9
00:00:50,784 --> 00:00:54,117
I think it's nice we're doing something
Maggie will enjoy for once.

10
00:00:54,220 --> 00:00:58,350
Besides, I'm sure Storytown Village
is also fun for everyone...
```

I'm trying to get certain values into a MySQL database but am completely stumped on how to do that with a regex and php.

I'd like to put the first time (i.e. 00:00:50) into "time" and any lines of text associated with that time into "text".

I'm not even 100% sure regex is the way to go, if there's an easier way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Comment: Thanks Ken, I'm not a coder (I can manipulate basic stuff but not much more) so I've been doing the google-copy-paste on a bunch of things I don't fully understand for a few days. This has just completely escaped me - too many moving parts that I'm struggling to piece together. So I'm admitting defeat and asking for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern would work:

```
$pattern = '/([\d,:]+) --> [\d,:]+\n(.*\n.*)[^\n\n]/m';
$string = "
8
00:00:45,879 --> 00:00:50,680
- Oh! Just leave me in the car with the window open a crack.
- That's the plan.

9
00:00:50,784 --> 00:00:54,117
I think it's nice we're doing something
Maggie will enjoy for once.

10
00:00:54,220 --> 00:00:58,350
Besides, I'm sure Storytown Village
is also fun for everyone..."; //Your File Contents Here

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This would result in:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 00:00:45,879 --> 00:00:50,680
```

- Oh! Just leave me in the car with the window open a crack.
- That's the plan.
            [1] => 00:00:50,784 --> 00:00:54,117
I think it's nice we're doing something
Maggie will enjoy for once.
            [2] => 00:00:54,220 --> 00:00:58,350
Besides, I'm sure Storytown Village
is also fun for everyone...
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 00:00:45,879
        [1] => 00:00:50,784
        [2] => 00:00:54,220
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => - Oh! Just leave me in the car with the window open a crack.
 - That's the plan
        [1] => I think it's nice we're doing something
Maggie will enjoy for once
        [2] => Besides, I'm sure Storytown Village
is also fun for everyone..
    )

)
```

Update:

```
foreach($matches[1] as $i => $data){
    $time = $data;
    $message = $matches[2][$i];
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Table (time,message) VALUES ('{$time}', '{$message}')");
}
```

Comment: Thanks sixeightzero, how would I get things out of the array into a mysql DB? I know that's a really simple question, but I'm a pretty low level guy and that's been one of the puzzle pieces I can't quite figure out.

Comment: Updated answer. The above should work, just change column and table names.

Comment: Thanks six, for some reason though my output is only showing `Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) )`    What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added the contents of your file to the variable $string above. It works fine if i copy and paste what is there. What version of PHP?

Comment: Hey Six, got it working, there must have been something wrong with my local machine. I also edited `[\d,:]+\n(.*\n.*)[^\n\n]/m'` to `[\d,:]+\n(.*\n?.*)[^\n\n]/m'` to be able to handle single lines of text. Then I changed `mysqli_query` into a `mysql_query` and added `$con = mysql_connect("LOCALHOST","USER","PASS");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("MY_DB", $con);`  -the mysqli_query didn't want to work for some reason. Thanks a bunch I learned tons from this!

Comment: Oh, and I had to escape the $matches[2][$i] so things didn't mess up when there was an `'` in the quote: `$message = mysql_real_escape_string($matches[2][$i]);`

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of delimiters within your text, so I wouldn't use a regex. Here is a solution using string manipulation:

```
$lines = explode( "\n", $str);

for( $i = 0, $ii = count( $lines); $i < $ii; $i += 5) {
    $num = trim( $lines[ $i ]);

    list( $line2a, $line2b) = explode( ' --> ', $lines[ $i + 1]);
    list( $time1, $val1) = explode( ',', $line2a);
    list( $time2, $val2) = explode( ',', $line2b);

    $text1 = $lines[ $i + 2];
    $text2 = $lines[ $i + 3];

    echo "$num $time1 $val1 $time2 $val2\n$text1\n$text2\n\n";
}
```

See [the demo](http://viper-7.com/vFcZed) to see which variables are assigned to which values from the file.

Comment: Thanks nick! If I wanted to read a file (or directory of files) rather than paste the text in, would I replace just '$str =' with '$filename = "file.txt"; 
$fp = fopen($filename, "r")'

Comment: No, you should put `$filename = 'file.txt'; $str = file_get_contents( $filename);` before the `$lines = ...`

Comment: Thanks again Nick, I tried it out and I'm getting errors about offsets. I think it's because some of the files have only a single line of text after the timestamp. I think I need to change `$lines[ $i + 1]);` but I'm not sure how to define the variable that says "it might be 1, 2 or 3 lines....just look for the blank line". I'm thinking that probably makes the string manipulation a bit harder? Sorry if it's an obvious answer

Comment: You'd need to post an example of the anomaly text in your question for me to be able to modify my example.

Comment: Hey Nick, I went back and re-did it this morning, apparently with a more clear head because it seems to be working now. Sorry about that. But, now instead of throwing errors, when it runs into a 1 liner: `2
00:01:05,231 --> 00:01:07,165
D'oh!` the next entry brings back the --> and doesn't catch the text i.e. `7 00:01:38,264 --> 00:01:40,255 8 00:01:40,366 --> 00:01:44,359 Hmm. ` (neither entry 7 or 8 have any text when they come after a 1 line entry)